# What class pattern, or package implements a dict with keys that countdown?

Tags: python, dictionary, ttl

I'm looking for a dictionary like object in which each key has a ttl (or countdown) that is decremented each time `.pop()` is called. When the counter hits 0 `.pop()` actually removes it. Something analogous to the Time-to-Live of network packets, which is measured in hops rather than seconds.

I'm guessing something like this exists, but I don't know the name.

```py
>>> d = X(); d.set('k', 'v', ttl=2); d.set('k2', 'v2', ttl=7)
>>> d.pop('k')
(1, 'v')
>>> d.pop('k')
(0, 'v')
>>> d.pop('k')
...
KeyError: 'k'
>>> d.pop('k2')
(6, 'v2')
```

What wheel am I reinventing?

Comment: Looks like a string key mapped to an iterator.

Comment: could you state your problem a little more clearly, please? Are you wanting to count down the ttl via the dictionary, or track multiple ttl values for different keys?

Comment: Try [this](http://repl.it/BGNL) implementation here.

Comment: It's unclear how you want the TTL to be enforced (I'm assuming you mean in seconds or something?). I don't think there is anything obvious in the standard library, especially if you want the dead objects to be garbage collected (using a WeakReference would help, but you still have some work ahead of you). The easiest thing to do is make a class with a clock that extends dictionary. You probably just need to override pop -- there you'll check if TTL > Clock and if so, raise the error (and probably delete while your at it)

Comment: I don't mean a TTL in seconds, I mean a TTL in calls-to-pop - like hops on a network. Each time a packet is forwarded the TTL is decremented. When the TTL reaches zero the packet is discarded.

Comment: Thank you @MalikBrahimi. I know it's a fairly trivial thing to write, but it feels like a design pattern that would already exist, and have a properly tested/documented/standardised implementation. I'm trying to find that.